# Can't connect to MySQL to VSCode Editor Error on my Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: mysql, sql-server, visual-studio-code

I've installed MySQL on my ubuntu 21.10 and it's working fine on the terminal I've installed MySQL extension on VSCode but when I am trying to connect to my VSCode editor but it displays an error

> mssql: Error: Unable to connect using the connection information provided. Retry profile creation?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SeOB.png)

Kindly please help

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - it seems you might have the wrong extension.

Comment: but I've installed SQL of Microsoft . should I reinstalled it?

Comment: The _SQL Server (mssql)_ extension from Microsoft is, funnily enough, an extension to connect to Microsoft SQL Servers. It doesn't connect to MySQL, which is something that speaks an entirely different protocol.